# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. (ReactJS + Spring Boot App)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm using ReactJS for the front end and Spring boot for the backend.
Whenever, I invoke this API:
`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/admin/member/checkIn?gymId=1&email=xyz@gmail.com`, I am getting: **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Here's my ReactJS code that makes the API call:

```js
export const checkInMembers = (gymId, email) => {
    const adminData = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("USER_DETAILS"));
    
    return axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/admin/member/checkIn', { gymId, email }, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${adminData.token}`,
        },
    });
}
```

Here's my Spring Boot code:

```java
package com.CMPE202.healthclub.controller;

import com.CMPE202.healthclub.entity.user.User;
import com.CMPE202.healthclub.entity.user.UserGymVisit;
import com.CMPE202.healthclub.exceptions.BadServerException;
import com.CMPE202.healthclub.exceptions.InvalidOperationException;
import com.CMPE202.healthclub.exceptions.RecordNotFoundException;
import com.CMPE202.healthclub.model.UserDetailsResponse;
import com.CMPE202.healthclub.service.AdminService;
import jakarta.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/admin")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RolesAllowed("STAFF")
@Validated
public class AdminController {
    private final AdminService adminService;
    @GetMapping({"/member"})
    public UserDetailsResponse getUserDetailsFromEmail(@RequestParam String email) throws RecordNotFoundException {
        return adminService.getUserDetailsFromEmail(email);
    }
    @PostMapping({"/member/checkIn"})
    public UserGymVisit checkInUserToGym(@RequestParam(required = true) Long gymId,
                                         @RequestParam(required = true) String email) throws RecordNotFoundException, InvalidOperationException, BadServerException {
        return adminService.checkInUsers(gymId, email);
    }
    @PutMapping({"/member/checkOut"})
    public UserGymVisit checkOutUserToGym(@RequestParam(required = true) Long userGymVisitId) throws InvalidOperationException {
        return adminService.checkOutUsers(userGymVisitId);
    }
    @GetMapping({"/member/currentCheckedInList"})
    public List<UserDetailsResponse> getAllCurrentCheckedInUsers(@RequestParam(required = true) Long gymId){
        return adminService.getAllCurrentCheckedInUsers(gymId);
    }
}
```

I even tried doing this. Still doesn't work!

```js
export const checkInMembers = (gymId, email) => {
    const adminData = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("USER_DETAILS"));
    const corsOptions = {
        origin: 'http://localhost:8080', // specify the URL of your server
    };

    const axiosInstance = axios.create();
    axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(cors(corsOptions));
    return axiosInstance.post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/admin/member/checkIn', { gymId, email }, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${adminData.token}`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
        },
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make cors configuration in backend side:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig{
     @Bean
      public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
          @Override
          public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
          }
        };
      }
}
```